# Use PHP in Array and Title For Wordpress Term Creation

Tags: php, wordpress, insert, categories

So I'm trying to create two categories when the user logs in. I need the category names to be the username of the user who is logging in.

I'm fairly new to PHP and I've been looking through the Codex and I know how to get the user information but I can't figure out how to make it output in the array or as the title.

The current code below is the closest I've gotten. It all works except the PHP code is not outputting. It shows as blank after the creation process.

```
function Login_CreateInitialCategories($user_login, $user) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    wp_insert_term(
        '<?php  echo $current_user->user_login; ?>',
        'outings',
        array(
          'description' => '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ; ?> Outings',
          'slug'        => '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ; ?>-category'
        )
    );

    wp_insert_term(
        '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ; ?>',
        'adventures',
        array(
          'description' => '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ; ?> Adventures',
          'slug'        => '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ; ?>-category'
        )
    );

}
add_action('wp_login', 'Login_CreateInitialCategories', 10, 2);
```

Do you guys know a way to get around this? The code is actually working perfectly, it's just not responding/outputting the PHP code.

Below is a link to a picture of the result of the code above. (I would of posted it here, but I don't have enough reputation.)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wamd6q3vd0odv7w/2015-05-08_02h52_10.png?dl=0

Comment: It has to do with the wp_login action. For some reason it doesn't let you use php as a value.

If you change the 'wp_login' to something else like 'wp_loaded' it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after working on a solution I decided to get the meta value directly and that worked.

```
function Login_CreateInitialCategories() {
    $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
    $user = get_user_meta($user_id = get_current_user_id(), nickname, true);
    wp_insert_term(
        $user, // the term 
        'outings', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'description'=> $user . ' Outings',
            'slug' => $user

  )
);

    wp_insert_term(
        $user, // the term 
        'adventures', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'description'=> $user . ' Adventures',
            'slug' => $user

  )
);  


}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'Login_CreateInitialCategories');
```

Answer (score 2):

What below code gives ??

```
    function Login_CreateInitialCategories($user_login, $user) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_login = $current_user->user_login;
        wp_insert_term(
            $user_login, //your term
            'outings', //your taxonomy
            array(
              'description' => $user_login.' Outings',
              'slug'        => $user_login.'-category'
            )
        );

        wp_insert_term(
            $user_login,
            'adventures',
            array(
              'description' => $user_login.' Adventures',
              'slug'        => $user_login.'-category'
            )
        );

    }
    add_action('wp_login', 'Login_CreateInitialCategories', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the above doesn't even create the term. That method was the first tried. You would think it should work.

Comment: Strange! It should work. Is it giving you any error ?

Comment: Make sure you have `outings` and `adventures` taxonomy already added before you add `terms` to it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_currentuserinfo()` instead of `wp_get_current_user()`.

```
function Login_CreateInitialCategories() {

    $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
    wp_insert_term(
        $current_user->user_login,
        'outings',
        array(
          'description'=> $current_user->user_email,
          'slug' => $current_user->user_login
        )
    );

    wp_insert_term(
        $current_user->user_login,
        'adventures',
        array(
          'description'=> $current_user->user_email,
          'slug' => $current_user->user_login
        )
    );

}
add_action('wp_login', 'Login_CreateInitialCategories', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Good idea, but the above doesn't create the term either.